# How to combine css and js files easily

Tags: website, css, merge, combine

For better maintenance I split my css and js files into many modules. However, when testing the site with https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly - Google is unable to load all files somehow. When I combine them together in one single file it works fine. But doing this manually is very troublesome.

I use Visual Studio Code. to edit and minify the files and save them directly to the server via Windows WebDAV. I am looking for an easy way to combine css and js files into a single file without having to buy an extra service or having a huge rollout setup.

I also read that this would be possible using the htaccess file, but unfortunately, the page is no longer available: http://isitvivid.com/blog/combining-your-cssjs-files-with-htaccess

Does anyone have a great idea?

Comment: You should be able to combine them using one copy command.

Comment: You mean with a bat file? I can't run ps1 files on the server due to security reasons, already tried...

Comment: Yes, even with the ancient [copy command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html). Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks! That was actually quite easy! `COPY ".\styles\*.css" ".\style.merged.css"`

Answer (score 0):

.bat file:

`COPY ".\styles\*.css" ".\style.merged.css"`